# ¿Como puedo mostrar un indicador gráfico de un proceso de copia iniciado desde el cmd de windows?

Tags: windows, cmd

Necesito saber cómo copiar con el copiador por defecto de windows desde el cmd.
Los comandos copy, xcopy y robocopy funcionan pero no son lo que realmente busco.
Imaginando que Explorer.exe es el proceso que se encarga de esto he buscado algún parametro que sirva para esto, pero no he tenido éxito..

Gracias de antemano...

Comment: Hola, y ¿qué es lo que realmente buscas? Porque con los que mencionas cubres mucho de lo que puedes hacer desde consola. El proceso que usa *Explorer* está pensado para uso con GUI.

Comment: Lo que realmente necesito es copiar con el copiador por defecto de windows desde el cmd, no tiene que ser obligatoriamente con explorer, pero imagino que sea el que se encarga de eso. No sé si me hago entender, gracias...

Comment: ¿A qué le llamas el ***copiador por defecto***? Desde D.O.S. 1.0, el copiador por defecto es `copy`. Luego apareció `xcopy` en la versión 3.6 del mismo S.O. Cuando Windows hizo entrada en escena, su implementación de `copy` se basaba en `xcopy`. Por último, `cmd` de Windows es simplemente un shell basado en D.O.S., por lo tanto sus comandos nativos (`copy` y `xcopy`) se ejecutarán mucho mejor. Puedes conseguir utilitarios que realicen tareas más sofisticadas en modo consola, pero más allá de realizar copias masivas su funcionalidad se puede equiparar a la de los dos ya mencionados.

Comment: Imagina hacer lo siguiente desde la interfaz de usuario: copiar un archivo de una carpeta hacia otra. Necesito hacer exactamente lo mismo desde el cmd con el progreso que se muestra y todo lo demás.... copy y xcopy lo hacen pero no me muestran el progreso y las demas opciones ue deseo... saludos...

Comment: Ahora entiendo que lo que deseas es la funcionalidad gráfica en la consola. Pues aparte de alguna aplicación que ya traiga dicha funcionalidad, puedes crear tu propia barra de progreso usando un archivo `batch`. No es tan complicado y puedes encontrar muchos tutoriales por la web. De resto, no podrás poner algo como la GUI de Windows desde el shell de D.O.S.

Comment: Realmente prefería la idea que tenia antes que esta, pero si no estaba claro de que se pudiera hacer, gracias por la ayuda...